# Can't use Twitter API to tweet special characters

Tags: c#, asp.net, twitter, oauth, restsharp

I'm creating a twitter bot that uses their API. The only package I'm using is RestSharp. If possible, I'd like a solution that doesn't include me using a helper package.

That's my code:

```
static bool tweet(string tweetstr)
{
    RestClient client = new RestClient("https://api.twitter.com");

    RestRequest r = new RestRequest("/1.1/statuses/update.json", Method.POST);

    //tweetstr = WebUtility.UrlEncode(tweetstr);
    //r.AddParameter("status", tweetstr, ParameterType.QueryStringWithoutEncode);
    r.AddQueryParameter("status", tweetstr);

    client.Authenticator = OAuth1Authenticator.ForProtectedResource(API_key, API_secret_key, access_token, access_token_secret);

    IRestResponse res = client.Execute(r);

    if (res.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString() + " Tweeted: " + tweetstr);
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Couldn't tweet!\nError code: " + res.StatusCode.ToString() + "\nTried to tweet: " + tweetstr + "\nResponse: " + res.Content.ToString());
        return false;
    }
}
```

Now for some reason, this works unless I use special characters in the string (such as foreign language or even an exclamation mark), if I do, it returns an Unauthorized error, the message is "Could not authenticate you.".

For example, calling `tweet("testing")` will work fine, but calling `tweet("testing!")` will return the error.

As you can see from the comments, I've tried encoding it myself but either the same error would get returned or it would post the tweet with the encoded status.

Any help? Thanks is advance!

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that does work, and one that doesn't.